# Spark can't get delimiter for CSV file

Tags: csv, pyspark

I have a CSV file like this [CSV read by pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x5oq.png) like this

But when I read it with PySpark, it turned out like this
[CSV read by PySpark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZBWd.png)
What's wrong with the delimiter in Spark and how can I fix it?

Comment: are you sure the delimiter is `","`? seems delimiter is a special character.

Comment: the result in pyspark says that the delimiter is %2C (which mean , in hex), I tried some encoding method but it didn't work.

Comment: can you post the output of `head -n 2 file.csv`?

Comment: As you can see in section [ASCII Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP), the `,` seems to be encoded to `%2C`. It is visible in the data snapshot. First check if the original CSV has it in that form. If yes, then decode it using some URL decoder library like `urllib.parse.unquote()`. If no, then post the file or portion of the file and source used to import.

Answer (score 0):

From the posted images, `%2C`, which is [URL encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) equivalent of `,`, seems to be your delimiter.

Set `delimiter` to `%2C` and also use `header` option:

```py
df = spark.read.option("header",True).option("delimiter", "%2C").csv(path)
```

Input CSV File:

```
date%2Copening%2Chigh%2Clow%2Cclose%2Cadjclose%2Cvolume
2022-12-09%2C100%2C101%2C99%2C99.5%2C99.5%2C10000000
2022-12-09%2C200%2C202%2C199%2C199%2C199.1%2C20000000
2022-12-09%2C300%2C303%2C299%2C299%2C299.2%2C30000000
```

Output dataframe:

```
+----------+-------+----+---+-----+--------+--------+
|date      |opening|high|low|close|adjclose|volume  |
+----------+-------+----+---+-----+--------+--------+
|2022-12-09|100    |101 |99 |99.5 |99.5    |10000000|
|2022-12-09|200    |202 |199|199  |199.1   |20000000|
|2022-12-09|300    |303 |299|299  |299.2   |30000000|
+----------+-------+----+---+-----+--------+--------+
```